# Error Logstash:”cannot link Java class io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl, probable missing dependency: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLContext.setCipherSuite

Tags: logstash, elk

We've upgraded our ELK stack from 6.4 version to 6.8.20 version. Elasticsearch and Kibana were upgraded without any issues. But we observed that Logstash service is restarting continuously after the upgradation.

**Elastic**: 6.8.20

**Kibana**:6.8.20

**Logstash**: 6.8.20

We found the below error logs in Logstash.

```
[ERROR][logstash.pipeline ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"<LogStash::Inputs::Beats codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>\"json :error=>"cannot link Java class io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl, probable missing dependency: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLContext.setCipherSuite(JLjava/lang/String;Z)Z", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x4768d63d run>"}

[2021-11-25T09:49:30,071][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<NameError: cannot link Java class io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl, probable missing dependency: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLContext.setCipherSuite(JLjava/lang/String;Z)Z>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:292:in `for_name'", "org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:288:in `for_name'", "org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:38:in `get_proxy_class'", "uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:44:in `block in java_import'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2577:in `map'", "uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:37:in `java_import'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-5.1.9-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:146:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:259:in `register_plugin'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:270:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1792:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:270:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:413:in `start_inputs'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:311:in `start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:217:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:176:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x4367d63d run>"}
[2021-11-25T09:49:30,091][ERROR][logstash.agent

[ERROR][logstash.pipeline ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"<LogStash::Inputs::Beats codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>\"json :error=>"cannot link Java class io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl, probable missing dependency: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLContext.setCipherSuite(JLjava/lang/String;Z)Z", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x4768d63d run>"}
```

Answer (score 1):

We were unable to resolve this issue while performing upgrade ELK upgrade logstash from 6.4 --> 6.8 --> 7.15 . To fix this issue we upgraded our Logstash directly to 7.15 ( all the other components were at 6.8 elastic, kibana, filebeat etc) .

7.15 (or 7.12) version comes with its own JDK and removes necessity to have jdk installed separately. Also the codecs written in JRUBY works perfectly here.

Comment: 7.15 version of logstash is backward compatible with 6.8 version

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this problem by having the beats input plugin listed before the http input plugin (? strange as it is, however this did solve the problem for me)

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-registering-plugin-beats-input/295596/2